# Kubernetes - specify externalips in configmap

Tags: kubernetes, config

I have a Kubernetes cluster (external ips: 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, 3.4.5.6)
I want to host a docker registry on this cluster on port 5000. Now to enable this I did a test with externalips, which works. This makes nginx available on port 85.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-extip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 85
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-extip
  externalIPs:
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 2.3.4.5
  - 3.4.5.6
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-extip
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-extip
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-extip-server
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Now to reuse the externalip config I want to put this into a configmap. So all yamls can just reference the configmap and we don't have to manually update the externalips when they change. How can I put an array of ips into the configmap?

My current (not working) configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: externalips
  namespace: default
data:
  externalips:
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 2.3.4.5
  - 3.4.5.6
```

The error I get:

```
error: error validating "static-ips-configmap.yml": error validating data: 
ValidationError(ConfigMap.data.externalips): invalid type for
io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "array", expected "string";
if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

How can I put these IP's into a configmap?

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here:

1. There is a syntax error in the creation of the configmap itself. Config map expects you to list a bunch of files and their contents, so the correct syntax would look something like this:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ConfigMap
   metadata:
     name: externalips
     namespace: default
   data:
     external-ips.list: |
       externalips:
       - 1.2.3.4
       - 2.3.4.5
       - 3.4.5.6
   ```
2. I don't think it's possible to refer to a configmap that you created to *template a service spec*. So even if you managed to create the configmap correctly, you still wouldn't be able to reuse it as part of different service definitions.

You need an out-of-band templating system that you can use to add these external IPs to services. Alternatively, use an ingress control, that you have to configure with external IPs *once* and then use it to multiplex all your HTTP services inside the cluster. This way you manage IPs for only one service anyway.

Comment: config maps do not list _a bunch of files and their contents_ but key -value pairs.These **might** be files and contents but that's not necessarily so.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch You're technically correct, but I felt phrasing it like that would've led to _more_ confusion in the answer. If you have a better way of phrasing it, please feel free to add an edit.

Answer (score 4):

ffledgling's answer is correct, but I think "external-ips.list" confuses a little bit.

This is what should look like the configmap yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: externalips
  namespace: default
data:
  externalips: |
    ips:
    - 1.2.3.4
    - 2.3.4.5
    - 3.4.5.6
```

So, "externalips", "ips", "external-ips.list" can be anything as those are just keys.